# WebMethod Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I am getting "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:5963/default.aspx/Call" when am calling this server side function using jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btn").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",`enter code here`
                        url: "default.aspx/Call",
                        data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        async: true,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert("sdsd");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:RadioButton  runat="server" ID="btn" Text="A" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static void Call(string value)
{
    var x = value;
}
```

Comment: What happens is you debug the server call?

Comment: it doesnt reach server call it throws a javasript error

Comment: did you try removing ScriptMethod leaving only WebMethod attribute?

Comment: your sure that when browsing to  http://localhost:5963/default.aspx/Call you're not getting a 500 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this script won't return anything because you're using the wrong id of a server control. When a server control is rendered, it's id changes.
Try using :

```
$("#<%=btn.ClientID %>")
```

You have another problem. You're calling an overloaded web method, so you need to pass some data :

```
data: "{'value': 'somevalue'}",
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks $("#<%=btn.ClientID %>") same as $("#btn") the problem was the overloading it works now

Comment: Important point to notice that the data must be in correct format. I CANNOT EMPHASIZE THIS ENOUGH! (Lost one hour because of this).

Answer (score 1):

Does this path `scripts/jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js` give you proper jQuery file? It looks like you're trying to load `vsdoc` file as a normal library.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.3.js"></script> i forgot to insert it here of course but for sure i added it

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is use the FireBug console. That will tell you what the error is.

But your code won't work because your return type is `void`. You actually need to return something back to the client. Change it to this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static string Call(string value)
{
    var x = value;
    return x; // Silly example
}
```